# deep link not working on real device, flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-deep-link

I use uniLinks package and it's work on android virtual device.
but not working on the real device and when I open link in browser, it's not come back to app.

```
 </intent-filter>

            <!-- App Links -->
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with https://YOUR_HOST -->
                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="payment.mlggrand.ir" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Comment: is it working when you open the link from  sms or  whatsapp or any other app?

Comment: Can you provide the code sample used to handle the deeplink, and an example of your deeplink?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.